# How to add the vertical alignment between Button and label programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel, ios-autolayout

Rather creating a Xib file and loading it into tableview. I am creating a label and button in Header view.

```
var btnTimeZone =  UIButton(type: .Custom)
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.btnTimeZone.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14.0)
    self.btnTimeZone.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.btnTimeZone.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.btnTimeZone.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.selectClicked), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 150))
    headerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    headerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    headerView.backgroundColor = ClientConfiguration.primaryUIColor()

    let myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width - 70, 30)
    myLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(10)
    myLabel.backgroundColor =  ClientConfiguration.primaryUIColor()
    myLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    myLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    myLabel.text = "please Select your Time Zone"
    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,headerView.frame.width , 50)
    self.btnTimeZone.frame = frame
    headerView.addSubview(myLabel)
    headerView.addSubview(self.btnTimeZone)
    return headerView
}
```

I want label above button in header view but I am not able to this..??
how can I do this..??

Comment: if you support iOS 9+ only you can use anchors

Comment: can you guide it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following to add a layout constraint via code:

```
let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item:myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem:headerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier:1.0, constant:0)
headerView.addConstraint(top)
```

Of course the issue would be that one constraint alone might not be enough and you'd need to add others to control the spacing between the label and the button and to also control the horizontal spacing for the elements.

Comment: does it add the label at the top of button..??

Comment: That would add the label with 0 padding to the headerView. Then you'd have to add another similar layout constraint to specify the spacing between the label and button. You could do all this much easier via storyboards though since you can specify everything visually :)

Comment: Are you able to share the full project with me by any chance? If you can, or if you can create a quick sample app which shows the issue, I can take a look and provide you with the code you'd need to get this done.

Comment: Yes, but in order to write code that actually works and test it, I need to set everything up and then add your methods from above. I am afraid that I don't have that much of time :) But if you were to provide the working code, I can quickly check what is going on, add a fix and let you know what the fix is.